# Find strings that start and end with certain characters

Tags: r, regex, unicode

I'm working on a text-mining project with data from twitter. In my data frame, many words are converted into Unicode characters, e.g.

> `<U+0E2B><U+0E25><U+0E07><U+0E1E>`

I want to collect every converted words like above and put them into 1 large string so I can deal with them separately.

Is there any way I can find all the strings that start with `<U+` and end with `>` using R?

Comment: Perhaps, you are looking for `grep("^(?:<U\\+[A-Z0-9]{4}>)+$", x)`

Comment: I've tried this with a row in my data frame, but somehow it gives the result: `integer(0)`

Comment: Please provide sample data with expected output.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/w3mVdm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is a bit imprecise, so I'm taking the liberty to make a few assumptions on how you want the output.

```
text <- "Words <Q+0E2B><U+0E2B2>, 1 < 2, <p> 
         <U+0E2B><U+0E25><U+0E07><U+0E1E> </p> some more words"

regmatches(text, gregexpr("<U\\+[0-9A-Z]{4}>", text))
# "<U+0E2B>" "<U+0E25>" "<U+0E07>" "<U+0E1E>"
```

Comment: Thank you this is the output I expected.